# Make Menu Entry efibootmgr Bash Linux

Tags: bash

I am newbie in bash linux.

I already make Boot Menu in Batch and Powershell. I want to make it in bash.

In bash, when i type efibootmgr, the output:

```
BootCurrent: 0003
Timeout: 2 seconds
BootOrder: 0011,0000,0001,0013,0014,0015,0004,0003,0016,0017
Boot0000* ThrottleStop UEFI
Boot0001* rEFInd Boot Manager
Boot0003* MX23 LinuX
Boot0004* Windows Boot Manager
etc...
```

I tried:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /home/mrkey7/Desktop/
sudo efibootmgr > file.txt
echo "$(grep "Boot00" file.txt)"
echo [R] Reboot
echo [S] Shutdown
echo [E] Exit

read -n 1 -p "Choose:" ans;
case $ans in
    r|R)
        sudo reboot;;
    s|S)
        sudo poweroff;;
    *)
        exit;;
esac
```

Output:

```
Boot0000* ThrottleStop UEFI
Boot0001* rEFInd Boot Manager
Boot0003* MX23 LinuX
Boot0004* Windows Boot Manager
[R] Reboot
[S] Shutdown
[E] Exit
Choose:
```

I want output like:

```
[1] ThrottleStop UEFI
[2] rEFInd Boot Manager
[3] MX23 LinuX
[4] Windows Boot Manager
[R] Reboot
[S] Shutdown
[E] Exit
Choose:
```

Then when i press "1", pc will boots to "ThrottleStop UEFI". Press "2" boots to "rEFInd Boot Manager". etc.

I try [@Grobu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22126467/grobu) code:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo efibootmgr  | awk '/^Boot[0-9]/{ gsub(/[Bot*0]/, "", $1)
Index = ++ $1; sub(/^\S+ /, "", $0)
printf("[% 2u] %s\n", Index, $0); }'

echo [R] Reboot
echo [S] Shutdown
echo [E] Exit
read -n 1 -p "Choose:" ans;
case $ans in
    r|R)
        sudo reboot;;
    s|S)
        sudo poweroff;;
    *)
        exit;;
esac
```

the Output:

```
[ 1] ThrottleStop UEFI
[ 2] rEFInd Boot Manager
[ 4] MX23 LinuX
[ 5] Windows Boot Manager
[ 2] Setup
[12] Boot Menu
[13] Diagnostic Splash
[14] USB FDD:
[15] ATA HDD: ADATA SU650
[16] USB HDD:
[17] USB CD:
[18] PCI LAN:
[R] Reboot
[S] Shutdown
[E] Exit
Choose:
```

new problem, new ask (maybe my first question wrong).
I don't want number greater than 9. So, i want to replace the output number with Alphabet sequance ABCDE
like this:

```
[A] ThrottleStop UEFI
[B] rEFInd Boot Manager
[C] MX23 LinuX
[D] Windows Boot Manager
[E] Setup
etc...
[1] Reboot
[2] Shutdown
[3] Exit
Choose:
```

> **Update Script** *after learning some commands.*

The Script work properly, but it seems less simple

Hope anyone can re-code better with simple code without re-create re-delete a temp file.

```
#!/bin/bash
test -f '/tmp/efi.tmp' && rm -f '/tmp/efi.tmp'
set -o nounset; C=0; AZ=( {A..Z} )
#Exclude: "Windows|FDD|PCI|CD|Splash"
sudo efibootmgr        \
| egrep -v "Windows|FDD|PCI|CD|Splash" \
| grep -e '^Boot[0-9]' \
| while read -r IDs Line
do printf '%s [%s] %s\n' "$IDs" "${AZ[C ++]}" "$Line" >> '/tmp/efi.tmp'; done
awk '{print $2,$3,$4,$5,$6}' '/tmp/efi.tmp'
echo '[1] Reboot'
echo '[2] Shutdown'
echo '[3] Exit'
    
read -s -n 1 -p ' Choose: ' ans;
case $ans in
    1) sudo reboot;;
    2) sudo poweroff;;
    3) exit;;
    a|b|c|d|e|f|g)
        ID="$(grep -i -F "[$ans]" '/tmp/efi.tmp' | grep -Eo "[0-9]{4}")"
        sudo efibootmgr -q -n $ID; sudo reboot;;
esac
```

I don't know yet:

- how to get 'efibootmgr' IDs from variable
- how to get "a|b|c|d|e|f|g" from variable

> **EFIBOOTMGR MENU**

> **Last Update**

Thanks to [@Gobu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22126467/grobu) for helps.

```
#! /bin/bash
function EFIBoot {
    clear
    FWDefID=$(efibootmgr | grep -e 'BootCurrent:' | awk '{print $2}')
    FWDefDE=$(efibootmgr | grep -e "Boot$FWDefID" | awk '{print $2,$3,$4,$5}')
    border='-------------------------------'
    echo Default Firmware $FWDefDE
    echo $border

    set -o nounset; Count=0
    declare -a Letters=( {A..Z} )
    declare -A Entries=()
    declare -u Answer=
    declare -u Press=

    while read -r BootID Description
    do  Index="${Letters[Count ++]}"
        printf '[%s] %s\n' "$Index" "$Description"
        Entries["$Index"]="${BootID#Boot}"
    done < <(efibootmgr | egrep -v "Windows|FDD|PCI|CD|Splash" \
    | grep -e '^Boot[0-9]\+' | tr -d '*')
    ValidLetters="$(echo "${!Entries[*]}" | tr -d ' ')"
    
    echo $border
    echo '[1] Shutdown   [6] Timeout EFI'
    echo '[2] Reboot     [7] Default EFI'
    echo '[3] Sleep      [8] Add New EFI' 
    echo '[4] Log Out    [9] Delete EFI' 
    echo '[5] Recovery   [0] Modify EFI'     
    echo $border
    
    read -n 1 -p 'Choose: ' Answer
    echo
    case "$Answer" in
        (1) sudo halt || sudo poweroff ;;
        (2) sudo reboot ;;
        (3) sudo pm-suspend || sudo systemctl suspend ;;
        (4) pkill -kill -u "$USER" ;;
        (5) echo 'not available yet' ;;
        (6) TimEFI ;;
        (7) DefEFI ;;
        (8) NewEFI ;;
        (9) RemEFI ;;
        (0) ModEFI ;;
        ([$ValidLetters])
            sudo efibootmgr -q -n "${Entries[$Answer]}"
            sudo reboot ;;
    esac
    EFIBoot
}

function DefEFI {
    read -n 1 -p 'EFI Label(A..Z): ' Press
    case $Press in
    ([$ValidLetters]) sudo efibootmgr -q -o "${Entries[$Press]}"
    esac
}

function TimEFI {
    TimeC=$(efibootmgr | grep 'Time')
    echo "Current $TimeC"
    read -n 1 -p 'Seconds: ' Time
    case $Time in
    ([0-9]) sudo efibootmgr -q -t $Time ;;
    esac
}

function NewEFI {
    ESP=$(sudo fdisk -l | grep -e 'EFI System' | awk '{print $1}')
    Disk=$(echo $ESP | tr -d '[0-9]')
    ESPPartNum=$(echo $ESP | tr -d '/a-z')
    ESPPath='/boot/efi/EFI'
    
    test -d "$ESPPath" && open "$ESPPath"
    echo 'Ex: Des "MXLinux", Loader "/EFI/MX23/grubx64.efi"'
    read -p 'Description: ' Des
    read -p 'Loader: ' Loader
    
    #remove '/boot/efi' if exist
    echo $Loader | grep -e "$ESPPath" && Loader="${Loader//'/boot/efi'/''}"
    if [ -f "/boot/efi/$Loader" ]; then
    sudo efibootmgr -c -L "$Des" -d "$Disk" -p "$ESPPartNum" -l "$Loader"
    fi
}

function RemEFI {
    read -n 1 -p 'Label EFI (A..Z): ' Press
    case $Press in
    ([$ValidLetters]) sudo efibootmgr -b "${Entries[$Press]}" -B ;;
    esac
}

function ModEFI { 
    echo 'not available yet'
}

#######
EFIBoot
```

Output:

```
Default Firmware rEFInd
-------------------------------
[A] MX23 LinuX
[B] rEFInd
[C] DisablePROCHOT EFI
[D] Setup
[E] Boot Menu
[F] ATA HDD: ADATA SU650
[G] USB HDD:
-------------------------------
[1] Shutdown   [6] Timeout EFI
[2] Reboot     [7] Default EFI
[3] Sleep      [8] Add New EFI
[4] Log Out    [9] Delete EFI
[5] Recovery   [0] Modify EFI
-------------------------------
Choose:
```

Comment: Do you want to store _both_ name and ID in one single variable while looping over the output of `efibootmgr`? Do you want to store these values in an array? Please elaborate as to what you want to do after you've retrieved those _name_ and _ID_ values.

Comment: the question was edited @Grobu

Comment: You could use `sudo efibootmgr  | awk '/^Boot[0-9]/{ gsub(/[Bot*0]/, "", $1); Index = ++ $1; sub(/^\S+ /, "", $0); printf("[% 2u] %s\n", Index, $0); }'`  (instead of `sudo efibootmgr > file.txt` and `echo "$(grep "Boot00" file.txt)"`) to produce your menu header. @Mr.Key7

Comment: Why `echo "$(grep …)"` and not just `grep …`? Also, you could combine that to just one `awk` script: `awk '/^Boot[0-9]/ {print "[" (++i) "]", $0}'`.

Comment: because I don't know many bash commands yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a suggestion:

```
#! /bin/bash

set -o nounset

declare -a Letters=( {A..Z} )

declare -A Entries=()

declare -u Answer

Count=0

while read -r BootID Description
do    Index="${Letters[Count ++]}"
      printf '[%s] %s\n' "$Index" "$Description"
      Entries["$Index"]="${BootID#Boot}"
done < <(efibootmgr | grep -e '^Boot[0-9]\+' | tr -d '*')

printf '%s\n' '[1] Reboot'   \
              '[2] Shutdown' \
              '[3] Exit'

ValidLetters="$(echo "${!Entries[*]}" | tr -d ' ')"

read -n 1 -p "Choose:" Answer

case "$Answer" in
     (1) sudo reboot ;;
     (2) sudo poweroff ;;
     ([$ValidLetters])
         sudo efibootmgr -q -n "${Entries[$Answer]}"
         sudo reboot ;;
     (*) exit ;;
esac
```

- `declare -a Letters=( {A..Z} )`
  ➥ *Letters* is declared as an indexed array
- `declare -A Entries=()`
  ➥ *Entries* is an associative array (aka a dictionary)
- `declare -u Answer`
  ➥ Set the *convert to uppercase* attribute. When *Answer* is assigned a value, that value is automatically converted to uppercase.
- `while ... done < <(efibootmgr | grep -e '^Boot[0-9]')`
  ➥ `<(...)` is a **process substitution** construct. Commands `efibootmgr | grep -e '^Boot[0-9]'` are run in a subshell, the output is stored into a temporary file whose name is substituted in place of `<(...)`
- `${!Entries[*]}`
  ➥ The `${!Dictionary[*]}` construct is substituted with the **keys** of the *Dictionary* associative array, in random order, separated by whitespace (by the first character of the `IFS` variable).

Hope that helps.

Comment: what's going wrong?. I tried and an error pop up: "...line 10: Count: unbound variable". No output efibootmgr displayed

Comment: The error gone by replacing "set -o nounset" with "set +u" based on this suggestion > https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/463034/bash-throws-error-line-8-1-unbound-variable

Comment: Please Update the answer again, @Grobu. The ID required is only 4 digits, not all of them. from your code, the value of "${Entries[$Answer]}" is all BootID.  Command "sudo efibootmgr -n Boot0013*" not work. Must "sudo efibootmgr -n 0013" for example.

Comment: I use code "echo ${Entries[$Answer]} | grep -Eo "[0-9]{4}"" to get '0013' from 'Boot0013*'. Maybe you can re-code better.

Comment: Not yet. Now "$Description" not shown. Only showing ["$Index"]. In my PC, Some BootID have an * at the end, others don't. Ex: Boot0013* Boot0011